# ios swift detect when hover over uiview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, hover

I am coding a iOS Swift 2 app and would like to show a subview for a certain amount of time when the parent view is "hovered" over with one's finger.

For example, I have a UIView that plays a video. When I hover over the view when the video is playing, I would like to temporary show another view that contains other content, such as a button to pause the video, a label that shows the total time of the video, etc.   But, I would like to fade out this content within a specific amount of time.

Any ideas?

Comment: You just need to know when the view is touched essentially, right?

Comment: The most straightforward solution that comes to mind is to use a custom `UIView` subclass that has `isUserInteractionEnabled` set to `true` and implements `touchesBegan(...`, `touchesEnded(...` etc.

Comment: FYI - Swift 2 support will be dropped in the near future. You really should update to Swift 3 before you have more and more code to convert. The sooner you do it, the better off you'll be.

Comment: Additionally, there is no "hover" on touch screens. We say "drag" :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`

```
let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "longPressed:")

self.view.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)
```

Handle your work here.

```
func longPressed(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
   *Do you work here*
}
```

If you want specific amount of time, you can use `minimumPressDuration`

```
longPressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 1.0
```